# Calculating Smoothing Capacitance

Tags: capacitor

I'm kinda new in this and I was wondering if I could get some help.

I am trying to build a AC-DC converter, through a full wave rectifier.
Ideally a 220V AC source, freq: 50hz stepped down to 22V AC and rectified to a DC voltage but I'm struggling to get a definite formula to calculate the smoothing capacitance.
I was planning to channel the output of the rectified DC to a 7812 voltage regulator.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you would have just searched this site you could have found: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/176661/low-voltage-ac-smoothing-capacitor-calculation

Comment: 22V AC when rectified will give you about 30V DC. The 7812 will have to drop 18V which may cause overheating if you draw any significant current from it.

Comment: @ Steve G, correct me if I'm wrong but if I was rectifying 22 AC, I would get about 15.55V by using the formula, Vpeak x 0.707?

Comment: AC voltages are normally specified by their RMS, rather than peak, value. Thus the peak is 22 sqrt(2) ~= 31 V, minus a diode drop or two due to rectification and whatever additional drop is acceptable due to load current and the limited size of the smoothing capacitor.

Comment: @ Oleksandr, thanks man!, I didnt know that, i really have to brush up on my fundametals then.

Comment: The smoothing capacitance depends upon your final load current, because the capacitors supply the current for a part of each half cycle of AC. You need to specify that value (or some maximum you will not exceed.)